# Фильтрация ListView. Как сделать полностью регистронезависимый поиск?

Tags: android, listview

Добрый вечер!
Имеется ListView, поиск в котором осуществлен через кастомный фильтр.
Поля, по которым идет поиск имеют формат "Имя Фамилия", т.е. первая буква - верхний реестр, остальные - нижний.

Написал вот так:

```
if(z.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint) || z.getName().contains(constraint) || z.getName().toUpperCase().contains(constraint))
```

т.е. учел варианты, когда человек вводит поисковый запрос "только в нижнем", "как есть" и "только в верхнем" реестрах.

Если вводить так - "иМя ФаМиЛиЯ" - поиск не осуществляется.
Как это обойти?
пример: в известном мессенджере ватсап можно хоть что писать в поиске... находит...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
z.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())
```

Comment: constraint это CharSequence. Не получается так... (

Comment: z.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase());
 В качестве микро оптимизации можете еще constraint.toString().toLowerCase() вынести в отдельную переменную до цикла с перебором.